# iPad saving audio save to local MusicDirectory

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, itunes, audio-recording

iOS 8.2
iPad a1474

inside app on IPAD, my code is

```
var dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
```

user records voice and it saves to

```
Optional(file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2B2028C4-8E7D-4D7F-9FAF-EB843F506A5E/Documents/audio-2015-01-25-144545.m4a)
```

in Itunes/App,

have tried

```
MusicDirectory and SharedPublicDirectory
```

with either of

```
LocalDomainMask or DocumentDirectory
```

none work with error

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

so what gives?

why can't app save to local MusicDirectory on the iPad???  there is nothing in the docs to indicate that this is protected area on the iPad.

no issues with iTunes or OSX, this is an iOS issue.

Comment: iOS is working, and OS X is not working? Please be clearer about what you are trying to do and what your problem is. Show the code to write & read the file and post the exact error message.

Comment: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: This error often occurs in a misleading way. You need to post the code including the context to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Under iOS8, the path that you have saved won't be the same across launches. The id you see "410AB24E-5FB0-4401-AC59-3C03D676E951" will change with each launch.

The workaround is to save the filename and not the complete path, and to recreate the URL or complete path, by getting the path to the Documents (or tmp) folder and appending the filename to it.